# Mapbox location image using lat long jomla itme

Tags: joomla, mapbox-gl-js

all

I am trying crating location images using mapbox API in my Joomla artical page check many articles but not getting proper answers when I search about this some articles say using lat long you can crate map image of particular location really appreciate is some one can help in this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Static image api [Link](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/)

and edit the parameters as per your requirement, and then it will return the url that you can enter in image api